# From second view under navigation bar

Tags: ios, controller, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller

i'm implementing a project with XCODE 5 and storyboard. I have added a view that is a `UIPageViewController` and when i `alloc` the first page (for this pageviewcontroller) the view appears normally but from second page the view appears under the navigation bar. What is the matter?

If i set this property

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

for the view displayed the problem is solved but when i go back from Page View Controller to previous View, the buttons on it are shifted down.

Why? What is the solution?

Furthermore if i set `translucent = NO` the views displayed in storyboard are different from views displayed in my app (the views are not shifted in storyboard).

I can't post images because i'm not authorized.

This is the code of my PageViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

variabiliGlobali = [foaGlobalVariable sharedInstance];
variabiliGlobali.giornataCalID = 1;

numeroGiornate = [variabiliGlobali.calendario count];
self.dataSource = self;
foaGiornataViewController *initialView = [[foaGiornataViewController alloc] init];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:initialView]
direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:NULL];
}
```

The foaGiornataViewController is a view that doesn't exist on storyboard but is only a `objective-c` `class`.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: It would be useful if you'd presented some code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't figure out how did you bind view controller on starboard and "foaGiornataViewController". Do you load views from storyboard at initiating a "foaGiornataViewController"?

Comment: I have a pageviewcontroller on my storybaord with a custom class. In this custom class i instantiate the views (pages) that there are not on storyboard.

Comment: Then I don't understand this phrase "the views displayed in storyboard are different from views displayed in my app", but it doesn't matter if you found the solution. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. I have setted opaque navigation bar for my Navigation Controller on storyboard.